# How can I sleep python requests without "Resetting dropped connection"?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, keep-alive

I'm currently working on a small python script that uses the `Requests` module to post a login, sleep for a short duration, and then submit a post again. However, even if I only have the script sleep for a tenth of a second with `time.sleep(0.1)`, I encounter the "Resetting dropped connection" message from the request library when the second request runs. I have already confirmed that the site supports keep-alive and everything works perfectly fine if there is no sleep between the first and second request. Is there any way to make the first request, wait, and then make a second with the same connection? Thanks!

**Update:** So far, the only other clue I've encountered is that the older `Mechanize` module doesn't seem to encounter this problem when sleeping between request. However, I would still prefer to use `Requests` for this project if possible.

**Update 2**: Looks like `Mechanize` actually has a similar re-connection delay but just doesn't note it in its log.

Comment: did your final solution work with Mechanize ?